# subscripting python module

Tags: python

I'm probably not using the right terminology, but I'm learning python and I'm trying something that I can easily do in Lua:

```
def fire(self):        
    return self._loadModule()[self._entrypoint]() #subscripting the module raises an error

def _loadModule(self):
    return __import__(self._module)
```

I want to load the module and then call an arbitrary function inside that module.  What is correct way to do this?

EDIT:
Module and entry point names are determined at runtime.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to `import modulename` and then do a `modulename.method()` call?

Comment: The truly correct, if sometimes (*rarely*) impractical, way is not to be *that* dynamic. Are you sure this is one of the few cases where such a thing is appropriate?

Comment: @thegrinner because `method` is not known until runtime

Comment: @delnan No, I'm not sure.  I'm porting some code from Lua and it's easier to write it the same way than to rethink it that much.

Comment: Rethinking may not be easier now, but it may very well result in everyone looking at the code in the future having less to think ;) Please describe what you want to do so we can suggest a better way.

Comment: @delnan I'm trying to demand load modules based on arguments passed from the command line.  Think SCM; `hg clone` would load the `clone` module and execute at some entry point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it right; a completely useless example:

```
def my_sqrt(num):
    import math #load a module
    return math.sqrt(num) #call the function
```

From string:

```
>>> def f(module, function, *args):
...     return(getattr(__import__(module), function)(*args))
... 
>>> f("math", "sqrt", 2)
1.4142135623730951
```

Comment: I want to call a function named in an argument, for example.

Comment: from a specified module, or the module is an argument too?

Answer (score 1):

```
mod = 'os'
func = 'listdir'
m = __import__(mod)
f = getattr(m, func)

import os
assert f is os.listdir
```

Answer (score 0):

`__import__('math').sqrt(2)` maybe?