# How is calling module and function by string handled in python?

Tags: python

[Calling a function of a module from a string with the function's name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3061) shows us how to call a function by using getattr("**bar**")(), but this assumes that we have the module **foo** imported already.

How would would we then go about calling for the execution of **"foo.bar"** assuming that we probably also have to perform the import of **foo** (or from **bar** import **foo**)?

Comment: something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6509967 ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'm still reviewing the responses for how well they fit with what I intended to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `__import__(....)` function:

[http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#**import**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__)

(David almost had it, but I think his example is more appropriate for what to do if you want to redefine the normal import process - to e.g. load from a zip file)

Comment: Works after a little coaxing, a better example should be given. I don't see a way to just import the function requested.

>>> a = __import__("foo.bar", globals(), locals(), ['baz',], -1)
>>> dir(a)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'baz', 'wok', 'horn']
>>>

Comment: I've finally revisited this. I'm accepting this because it put me in the direction I wanted. I've posted the final solution I've come up with

Comment: I would also recommend looking into [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module): `from importlib import import_module` and then use `import_module(...)` in your code. It's a simplified `__import__` without all the args.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find_module` and `load_module` from the [`imp`](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html) module to load a module whose name and/or location is determined at execution time.

The example at the end of the documentation topic explains how:

```
import imp
import sys

def __import__(name, globals=None, locals=None, fromlist=None):
    # Fast path: see if the module has already been imported.
    try:
        return sys.modules[name]
    except KeyError:
        pass

    # If any of the following calls raises an exception,
    # there's a problem we can't handle -- let the caller handle it.

    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(name)

    try:
        return imp.load_module(name, fp, pathname, description)
    finally:
        # Since we may exit via an exception, close fp explicitly.
        if fp:
            fp.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i finally came up with to get the function i wanted back out from a dottedname

```
from string import join

def dotsplit(dottedname):
    module = join(dottedname.split('.')[:-1],'.')
    function = dottedname.split('.')[-1]
    return module, function

def load(dottedname):
    mod, func = dotsplit(dottedname)
    try:
        mod = __import__(mod, globals(), locals(), [func,], -1)
        return getattr(mod,func)
    except (ImportError, AttributeError):
        return dottedname
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution is not working?
[Calling a function of a module from a string with the function's name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python/4605#4605)